# Is there a way to exclude jackson library from kafkaStreams?

Tags: apache-kafka, jackson, gson, apache-kafka-streams

When i am trying to exclude jackson library from a Maven dependency in my pom.xml, and trying to run the streaming application, I am getting an error on stateDirectory.java from kafkaStreams as it uses jackson library internally.

I am trying to replace jackson with Gson in my streaming application as the 2021 benchmarks are in favor with Gson.

Comment: 1) Benchmarks should be ran on your own machine, not trusted from external resources 2) Have you tried to not use `JSONSerde` / `JSONSerailizer` builtin classes?

Comment: I had tried both before, but now since I have excluded jackson from kafkaStreams dependency, I don't have access to jackson library to access these serde.
So i have created my own for gson library.
But the question is more about if jackson dependency mandatory for kafkaStreams ?

Comment: It's used internally to the Kafka API, yes. Source code is on Github if you want to look... What specific error do you get? If fully excluded, you'd see ClassNotFound exceptions